# Kerberos host authentication

Tags: linux, security, authentication, kerberos

I've set up a kerberos server with following configuration

krb5.conf:

```
[logging]
default = FILE:/var/log/krb5libs.log
kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log
[libdefaults]
  default_realm = DOMAIN.NET
  dns_lookup_realm = true
  dns_lookup_kdc = true
  ticket_lifetime = 24h
  renew_lifetime = 7d
  forwardable = true
[realms]
  DOMAIN.NET= {
  kdc = server.priv.domain.net
  admin_server = server.priv.domain.net
 }

[domain_realm]
 .domain.net = DOMAIN.NET
  domain.net = DOMAIN.NET
```

kdc.conf

```
[kdcdefaults]
kdc_listen = 88
kdc_tcp_listen = 88

[realms]
DOMAIN.NET = {
    database_name = /usr/local/var/krb5kdc/principal
    acl_file = /usr/local/var/krb5kdc/kadm5.acl
    key_stash_file = /usr/local/var/krb5kdc/.k5.DOMAIN.NET
    kdc_listen = 88
    kdc_tcp_listen = 88
    max_life = 10h 0m 0s
    max_renewable_life = 7d 0h 0m 0s
```

I thought that, kerberos accepts authentication request from host, which has keytab issued from kerberos server. But  it seems to me, it serve authentication from everywhere even, there is no host principal and keytab have been set up.
Could somebody please advise?

Thanks,

P

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the principal for your host has been created on the server, one needs to run `ktadd` from `kadmin` shell

`ktadd -k /etc/krb5.keytab host/blah.DOMAIN.NET`

Exit the `kadmin` shell and run `klist` to verify that you have obtained a Kerberos ticket.

[1] - https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Managing_Smart_Cards/Configuring_a_Kerberos_5_Client.html

Comment: Hi NOLFXceptMe, it seems my server serves every host even the client host principal hasn't been created nor added keytab. So, the question is, why does the server serve authentication for clients without client principals and keytab?

Comment: Only a secure service would request for Kerberos based authentication and deny unauthenticated requests. I'm not sure what service is being served to the client. Do you mean LDAP authentication?

Comment: Hi, I'm able to authenticate user, using kinit on any host, just simply set up krb5.conf without host principal or deploy keytab. I  expected that​ the krb server reject any authentication from everywhere without host principal and keytab. But my server still  does authenticate...

Comment: Hi, what is the output of klist? If you have a valid output, I think we can be sure of a keytab existing on the host.

Comment: Well,  If I didn't created ANY host principal and generated keytab(thisis the case), but I'm still able to use this kerberos server to authenticate via SSH and NIS(with krb_pam modul) means to me, my kerberos server authenticate without host principal and keytab.
Again, I expected to kerberos server only authenticates IF host principal present and keytab in the client host has been deployed. Non of these requirements are present on the client, SSH login still work..why?